# Internet explorer errors: 'Expected identifier' and 'Object expected'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Hello I am getting this error in IE when i load any js file what should I do?
Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Timestamp: Tue, 1 Mar 2011 18:34:03 UTC


Message: Expected identifier
Line: 26
Char: 21
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/learning/public/js/general.js


Message: Object expected
Line: 5
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/learning/public/js/tests.js
```

Comment: Could you check your addons. Things like a yahoo tool bar. I will disable all addons and then try again. *

Comment: Apparently, there should be an object on line 5, and an identifier on line 26.  Without your JS code, we cannot help you.

Comment: Question doesn't belong on StackOverflow

Answer (score 5):

It is likely either as @g.d.d.c says, a problem with a trailing comma, or the error comes from using [reserved key words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). When Explorer sees variable names like `super`, `class` and `exports` it will strip those away before evaluating the code.

```
class = 'asdf';
```

… becomes …

```
= 'asdf';
```

And thus there is no identifier to assign the `'asdf'` string to.

Answer (score 4):

I'm willing to wager the cause is an extra comma at the end of an Object Declaration:

```
var valid = {
  'key': 'Value'
};

var invalid = {
  'key': 'Value',
};
```

Google Chrome / Firefox and I believe Safari are intelligent enough to ignore the extra comma.  Internet Explorer sees the comma and expects another property to be assigned to the Object.