# Is converse.js supported in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, converse.js

When I try to view the converse.js demo I get the following errors

converse.js and Internet Explorer 11 error:

[image: converse.js and Internet Explorer 11 error]

Changing compatibility settings doesn't fix the issue.

I've also setup a copy of converse.js in my environment and I've tried cleaning up trailing commas as suggested in this post

[Internet explorer errors: 'Expected identifier' and 'Object expected'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158796/internet-explorer-errors-expected-identifier-and-object-expected)

but then, I get different errors

Error in Internet Explorer 11 - without trailing commas

[image: Error in Internet Explorer 11 - without trailing commas]

This is the code I have (which works when viewed through Chrome or Firefox).

Could anyone suggest what I could to do make it work in IE11? Is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    converse.plugins.add('myplugin', {
        initialize: function () {
            var _converse = this._converse;
            this._converse.api.waitUntil('connected').then(function () {
                var chat = _converse.api.chats.open('topic1@pcechlt46.pce.local');
                console.log("function SENDING MESSAGE");
                var msg = converse.env.$msg({
                    from: _converse.jid,
                    to:'topic1@pcechlt46.pce.local',
                    type:'chat'
                }).c('body').t('hello world');
               _converse.api.send(msg);
            });
        }
    });


        converse.initialize({
            bosh_service_url: 'http://pcechlt46.pce.local:7070/http-bind/',
            authentication: 'anonymous',
            show_controlbox_by_default: true,
            auto_login: true,
            jid: 'pcechlt46.pce.local',
            allow_muc: false,
            allow_contact_requests: false,
            allow_chat_pending_contact: true,
            allow_non_roster_messaging: true,
            allow_otr: false,
            play_sounds: true,
            sounds_path: '/converse/sounds/',
            notification_icon: '/converse/logo/conversejs.png',
            allow_muc_invitations: false,
            show_desktop_notifications: true,
            debug: true,
            whitelisted_plugins: ['myplugin'],
            // Blacklist plugins which aren't included in the build file,
            // so that other code cannot register their own plugins under
            // those names.
            blacklisted_plugins: [
                "converse-bookmarks",
                "converse-controlbox",
                "converse-headline",
                "converse-otr",
                "converse-register",
                "converse-vcard",
            ]
        });





</script>
```

Comment: see if fixing the malformed comment error (markup) fixes it.... IE9 Emulation mode and lower only support conditional comments...other browsers do not use or recognize them.

if possible include a reproduction url with your question......

Comment: Hello Rob. The malformed comment error (first screenshot) shows up on the ConverJS DEMO site. I can't change the contents of that page, but it could be reached from anywhere.

https://conversejs.org/demo/anonymous.html

However, on my local copy of conversejs I don't have any comments on my HTML so I don't get any errors related to malformed comments (second screenshot).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Trend Micro AV installed? 'crypto undefined' is an error signature of a faulty Trend Micro Addon for IE. see this TechNet thread - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/db151c0b-c563-4244-a8e5-f6bd9361716b/ie-11-crashing-on-windows-7-x86-workstations-cryptnetdll?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: Hi, Rob Parsons. I don't have Trend Micro installed. JCBrand fixed this issue on release 3.2.1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. JCBrand (ConverseJS developer) has confirmed that this version is not working in IE11 and will be releasing a fix on a future release.